# What is best practice to initialize test data before usage?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

I have a multiple property files with params like this

```
login-page.login-button.text 

login-page.notification.wrong-password
```

And this values should be used in assertions like this

```
Assert.that(actualNotification, expectedNotificationFromProperties)
```

Is there better way than create multiple classes with public static final fields, which will be initialized by some property reader?

Solution without spring framework would be perfect for me

Comment: this probably depends on who is doing the updating of those variables and the overall structure of the code/tools used/page objects/outside files... could use more details like: what is the reason for doing it the way you are currently doing it?  and details about the current method.  (a more focused question would be good...)